# @JWT_Required decorator Exception Handling

Tags: flask, flask-jwt-extended, flask-jwt

I am using an auth API using JWT and it works great.
This API is being used to authorize users for my web app. For this to work, I store JWT access_tokens as cookie manually with Flask. 
I secure my resource with @JWT_required decorator and if I try to access a secure resource with a valid token everything works fine.
However, if the access token is missing or invalid/expired I get a JSON saying:

```
{
      "message": "Missing cookie \"access_token_cookie\""
}
```

This is obvious the right message but rather then showing a JSON I want to redirect to the appropriate statuscode error page that is provided by Flask - in this case 401.

- I have tried adding error handling for Flask and JWT Manager
- Custom decorator, although I have played only poorly with this as I believe there has to be solution within FLASK-JWT-extended

```py
@app.route('/dashbord')
@jwt_required
def dashbord():
    return render_template('dashbord.html', title='Home')
```

*My goal is to redirect to appropriate error page 404, 403, 401 if anything is wrong with the access token.*

THE SOLUTION:

```py
@jwt.unauthorized_loader
def my_invalid_token_callback(expired_token):
    return render_template('401.html', title='Home')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution Benjo posted at the bottom of his question:

```
@jwt.unauthorized_loader
def my_invalid_token_callback(expired_token):
    return render_template('401.html', title='Home')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation for changing the results for invalid tokens: https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changing_default_behavior.html#changing-callback-functions

Comment: Thaks for your help.I found that part of the documentation earlier and played around with it. HoweverI couldnt find the right one. What one can I use for @JWT_requried?

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Found the right one: @jwt.unauthorized_loader
def my_invalid_token_callback(expired_token):
    #token_type = expired_token['type']
    '''
    return jsonify({
        'status': 401,
        'sub_status': 42,
        'msg': 'The {} token has expired'.format(token_type)
    }), 401
    '''
    return render_template('401.html', title='Home')